# How to implement web app Oauth Popup Youtube API call for beginners

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Are there any updated beginner tutorials on how to implement the Google OAuth 2.0 popup authorization so my web app clients can use the Youtube Data API?

[Google Auth Popup commonly found in websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5JcM.png)

The Google quickstart documentation only goes through the console flow.

I've tried the Oauth2.0 for Web Server Application guide, but it's it makes no sense to me and it's also in Flask.

All guides I've followed from Google use deprecated packages. All the guides are also different from each other.

This is code the achieves what I need. However, instead of using the Google authentication popup, it asks me to go onto the console.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']

API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'


class youtube_base:
    # Working auth code
    def get_authenticated_service():
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = flow.run_console()

        return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```

This is how I call the Youtube API in my web app:

```
class YtAuthView(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = YtAuthForm
    template_name = 'yt_auth_update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        client = youtube_base.get_authenticated_service()
        stats = get_channel_stats(client, self.object.youtube_channel_id)

        form.instance.yt_subscribers = stats['totalSubs']
        form.instance.yt_views_avg = stats['viewsAverage']
        form.instance.yt_views_median = stats['viewsMedian']
        form.instance.yt_eng_rate = stats['engagementRate']
        form.instance.yt_last_updated = stats['dataRecorded']

        response = super(YtAuthView, self).form_valid(form)

        return response
```

Comment: You have some examples in https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python

Comment: These examples use the deprecated oauth2client packages or use the console flow.